# Securely Pass/Retrieve Referrer Page in PHP via GET?

Tags: php, security, redirect, get, referrer

I have read several posts pertaining to redirecting to the previous page upon user action login/etc. and most mentioned that getting the previous page url via HTTP_REFERRER is non-reliable/insecure.

My question is, could I append a bit of info to the end of the URL say, `login.php?referrer=main` or `login.php?referrer=prof`, and rely on such variables to not be spoofed, CRSF'd, altered in any way?

Would POST be better/worse?  Is there any reliable/secure way to achieve what I am after?

Basically, I am trying to find the best way to get the referring page in PHP so that it can be redirected to without the risk of malicious intentions causing site malfunctions.

TIA.

EDIT: Scenario:

A user visits a comment page, but needs to be logged in to post a comment, so a `login to comment` link would be placed on the page.  When the user clicks the `login to comment` link, its target would be login.php?comment20303, upon visiting the login page and supplying verified credentials, they should be taken back to the comment20303 page they originated from prior to logging in.

REEDIT: My question boils down to, is appending the redirect url to the login page, accessing it via GET, and re-using it to return them to the original page secure?  It seems from the comments below that the answer is no, not without some validity checks.

Answer (score 0):

Often I will place the referring page into a hidden field in my form

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref" value="login.php"/>
```

Then in my target page I will use the referral with get variables set to tell the login page why it has been re-directed back

```
$ref = trim(strip_tags($_POST['ref']));

//something causes an error (incorrect password maybe)======
$error = "true";
$msg = urlencode("Login Incorrect");
//no harm in putting the referring page in the GET but I don't think you need it for a login process.
header('location: '.$ref.'?error='.$error.'&msg='.$msg);
die();
```

Back in the login page I will handle the error if it is set which tells me I came from the form target and there was an error

```
if (isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == "true"){
    $error = true;
    $msg = trim(strip_tags($_GET['msg']));

//Echo out the msg if it is set somewhere in your HTML
}
```

I prefer to use POST when submitting a form. GET is easiest to use for a re-direct.

EDIT: BASED ON YOUR COMMENT

1. user is entering comment and the comment has a system generated id.
2. user is not authenticated so is redirected to reg/login with ID in URL
3. user registers/logs in again pass the ID in URL
4. system authenticates and because thereis a $_GET['commentID'] it inserts a db entry associating the user to the comment
5. return user to the comment editing area with ID in URL and handle.

Always trim and strip the GET

Comment: The way I plan to use it is on say, a comment page, when a user is not logged in, they cannot post a comment, so I was thinking add `ref=comment20304` to the end of the login URL, i.e. `login.php?comment20304`, so once the user has verified their login via login.php, they can be redirected back to the page they were viewing prior to logging in.  I had also considered POST, however, I read somewhere that POST is not secure either.  Basically I want something secure so that my users are not redirected to old-xxx-ladies.com, etc., instead of comment20304.

Comment: Sure, adding the comment id is fine as long as you associate the id with the new user before sending them back to the comment editing area. This way they can not try different id's and edit them as they have to be associated with the user.

Comment: yep and so is a GET. And from what I hear, anything sent via HTTP. So you have to put some logic checks in there and validate what you are getting.

Comment: @silversunhunter: I think a partial redirect value and some logic checks is what I need to go with as the more I think about it, as long as I do not append/POST the entire url `login.php?ref=sitename.com/comment49043`, but rather simply the id of the comment page they were on prior to logging in, there should not be a security risk because if the comment id is not found, or is invalid, I could simply add an alert / error routine that would redirect them to a default page, such as their profile, etc. on error.

Comment: @baao: I had read that CSRF token could be helpful, but I don't even know where to start as far as implementing such a strategy.

Comment: True but I would go one step further and associate the comment ID to the user as well. If I see that I am on the comment page and the ID in the URL is 123, I may try 124,125 or any number until I find one that is open to edit. The system needs to check and make sure this comment belongs to me before letting me edit it.

Comment: This is a little tutorial for the start http://bkcore.com/blog/code/nocsrf-php-class.html

Comment: @silvershunter: I am speaking of simply adding a comment to say a forum thread.  The user would need to be logged in to do so, however, the "thread" they are on can be commented on by any logged in individual, in this case, i think all I would need is the "thread" id.  Then, I can put a check on the thread page to be sure the "thread" id is actually for a valid thread found in the database, and if not, redirect to a "thread not found" page.  However, if the thread being commented on had certain privelages, I would need to check their user id, etc. to be sure they can view/add-to the thread.